# What is the name of this young-adult book series from the '90s featuring miniature aliens?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

This was a book series I read when I was younger.

It featured a boy in his early teens who was contacted by aliens in a miniature space ship.  He is soon shrunk down to their size and becomes a member of the ships crew.  I believe they are some sort of galactic police force.

They go on several adventures over the course of a few books.

I believe the main villain in the story attempts to freeze time in his moment of ultimate triumph.  There might also be some sort of search for the boys father.

Comment: Not to be nitpicky, but I think you mean "the '90s"?

Comment: That must have been really satisfying for you.

Comment: I take it that's a "yes."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you thinking of [Aliens Ate my Homework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens_Ate_My_Homework) by Bruce Coville.  There are additional novels in the series which are:

- [I Left My Sneakers in Dimension X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Left_My_Sneakers_in_Dimension_X)
- [The Search For Snout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Search_For_Snout)
- [Aliens Stole My Body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens_Stole_My_Body)